# PHP, JQuery ajax not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Issue seems to be that it's firing the error handler, never the success..

```
$('#editPlaceForm').submit(function() {
        var placeName = $('#placeName').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../FormHandlers/myPlaces.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {update_Place:true, place_Id : placeId, place_Name : placeName },
            success:function(json) {
                var result = JSON.parse(json);
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#editPlaceModal').modal('hide');
                    if (locationsTable) {
                        locationsTable.fnDraw();
                    }
                }
            }, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Sorry, an error occurred: Thrown: ' + errorThrown + ', Request: ' + XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders().toString() +
                ', TextStatus: ' + textStatus + ', Please try again.');
            }
        });
    });
```

Server-side being called via ajax:

```
if (isset($_POST['update_Place'])) {

    $place_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['place_Id']);
    $place_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['place_Name']);

    $update = "UPDATE locations SET name='" . $place_name . "' WHERE id =" . $place_id . ";";

    $db->query($update);
    $db->commit();
    $db->close();

    echo json_encode(array('success'=>'Changes were saved.'));
}
```

Many thanks..................................

Comment: And what error are you getting? Try `console.log()` instead of `alert()` so that you can more easily copy and paste the error into your question. (Note that you don't need to use `JSON.parse()` within your `success` handler, jQuery will parse it for you before calling the function because you specified `dataType: 'json'`. This isn't causing your current problem, but once you solve the current problem it would be your _next_ problem.)

Comment: I believe that this `data: 'updatePlace=' + JSON.stringify(data)` is incorrect since you do a post type not get you should try this instead `data: {updatePlace: JSON.stringify(data)}`

Comment: hmm, I tried data: { updatePlace: ... } seems to be giving me the same result. There's nothing showing up for Thrown or Request, and TextStatus: just says 'error'

Comment: @mapleafman then most likely the problem is even before that, just like a Lex noted in his answer.

Comment: Do you have `<input type='text' name='updatePlace' />`, on your form? The `name` is what I'm getting at. If not, it won't work.

Comment: @JasonBuckley hmm no I don't have it on the form. Why would I need it?

Comment: Yes, PHP `$_POST` data comes from the `name` attribute.

Comment: @nnnnnn just showing '[object Object], error' in console when I do: console.log(XMLHttpRequest + ', ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);

Comment: To see if the error doesn't come from your PHP script you can: `console.log(JSON.parse(json))` use that value for a text input and post that to your php (with a submit button) so you can see what the php does and if it causes an error. In firefox the xhr request should show up in your console and you can inspect it's content there as well (check for response headers).

Comment: Seems like the `errorThrown` is blank, but for future reference don't do a `+` string concatenation of `XMLHttpReqest` - log each argument separately.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that jumps at me is this:

`url: '../FormHandlers/myPlaces.php',`

I am not sure where and how the '..' is handled, but you can write to a log from your php to check if the script file is even being run.